# Setting time in new date variable javascript

Tags: javascript

A few months ago I made a script, which works perfectly for setting the time of a specific date variable.

```js
var select_date = "2020-07-14";
d = new Date(select_date + "T16:00:00");
 
document.getElementById("test-time").innerText = d;
```

```html
<p id="test-time"></p>
```

But now I want to use this script without setting a specific date with variable `select_date`. So I just want to select today and set the time to 16:00.

So something like this:

```
d = new Date("T16:00:00");
```

However I keep getting the error invalid time. And I searched a lot on google, but can't find anything. Does anyone know why it doesn't work this way?

Comment: You can't have a `Date` without a date. You'd need a `Time` class for that, which Javascript doesn't have built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
const d = new Date();
    d.setHours(16);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    console.log(d.toString());
```